# Dagger 2 Not injecting into dependant module

Tags: android, module, null, inject, dagger-2

I checked all questions but did not find any clue. I stripped my problem to a simplest code:

Situation:
I want to have:

```
    CatComponent catComponent = DaggerCatComponent.builder()
        .kameModule(new KameModule(MainActivity.this))
        .build();
   catComponent.getCatAnalyzer().analyze();
```

I have created component:

```
@Component(modules = {KameModule.class, CatAnalyzerModule.class})
public interface CatComponent {

    CatAnalyzer getCatAnalyzer();
}
```

And modules:

```
@Module
public class KameModule {

    private Context context;

    public KameModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    KameCat provideKameCat() {
        return new KameCat(context );
    }
}

@Module(includes = KameModule.class)
public class CatAnalyzerModule {

    @Inject
    KameCat cat;

    @Provides
    CatAnalyzer provideCatAnalyzer() {
        return new CatAnalyzer(cat);
    }
}
```

And classes:

```
public class KameCat {

    Context context;

    public KameCat(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void doCatStuff() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Poo and Meow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public class CatAnalyzer {

    @Inject
    KameCat cat;

    @Inject
    public CatAnalyzer(KameCat cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    void analyze() {
        cat.doCatStuff();
    }
}
```

When I retrieve my CatAnalyzer object from CatComponent it has `cat` field **nulled**.
I have no idea why Dagger won't inject it. Could you guide me somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Proper code:

```
@Module(includes = KameModule.class)
public class CatAnalyzerModule {

    @Inject //remove this
    KameCat cat;// remove this

    @Provides
    // Add cat as a argument and let KameModule provide it..
    CatAnalyzer provideCatAnalyzer(KameCat cat) {
        return new CatAnalyzer(cat);
    }
}
```

Thanks to: 
https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2/

Comment: Your `@Inject` annotations on the are redundant since the class is being provided in your `CatAnalyzerModule`. You could remove the module since, or the `@Inject` annotation on the constructor. Either way, the `@Inject` annotation on `KameCat cat` is superfluous.

Comment: Also, for more idiomatic DependencyInjection, the `KameModule` would `@Provides` the context so it can participate anywhere in any module. Then the `provideKameCat` method can take a `Context` as a parameter as well, similar to what you're doing with `provideCatAnalyzer(KameCat cat)`

Comment: And lastly, the `@Module.includes` is not necessary if you end up including both modules in the `@Component.modules` list.